# College retention in R using dplyr and nested loops

Tags: r, nested-loops, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr and nested loops in R to produce retention data setfor college students.

```
student <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z")
term <- c("2118", "2122", "2128", "2132", "2118", "2122", "2128", "2118", "2128",
"2132", "2138", "2128", "2132", "2128")
status <- c("New", "Continuing", "Continuing", "Continuing", "New", "Continuing",
"Continuing", "New", "New", "Continuing", "Continuing", "New", "Continuing", "New")
match <- c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M")
# match is any variable from original dataset used for matching purposes
df <- data.frame(student, term, status, match)
> df
   student term     status match
1        A 2118        New     M
2        A 2122 Continuing     M
3        A 2128 Continuing     M
4        A 2132 Continuing     M
5        B 2118        New     M
6        B 2122 Continuing     M
7        B 2128 Continuing     M
8        C 2118        New     M
9        X 2128        New     M
10       X 2132 Continuing     M
11       X 2138 Continuing     M
12       Y 2128        New     M
13       Y 2132 Continuing     M
14       Z 2128        New     M
```

I use two loops to separate each cohort based on their `status` as a new student and also all enrollment for the `term`

```
cohorts <- c("2118", "2128")
semester <- c("2118", "2122", "2128", "2132", "2138")
library(dplyr)
for (i in cohorts) {
  assign(paste('c',i,sep=''),
         df %>%
           filter(term == i, status == "New") %>%
           select(student, term))
}
for (i in semester) {
  assign(paste('s',i,sep=''),
         df %>% 
           filter(term == i) %>%
           select(student, match))
}
```

Next, I begin chaining all the verbs in `dplyr` to create retention, but the code becomes too long especially when using many cohorts (`retention03` ... `retention13` is the most recent cohort) and also finding retention up to 8 semesters after enrolling (`Retained1` ... `Retained8`)

```
retention11 <- c2118 %>%
  left_join(s2122) %>%
  mutate(Retained = !is.na(match)) %>%
  mutate(Retained1 = ifelse(Retained == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>%
  select(student, term, Retained1) %>%
  left_join(s2128) %>%
  mutate(Retained = !is.na(match)) %>%
  mutate(Retained2 = ifelse(Retained == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>%
  select(student, term, Retained1, Retained2) %>%
  left_join(s2132) %>%
  mutate(Retained = !is.na(match)) %>%
  mutate(Retained3 = ifelse(Retained == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>%
  select(student, term, Retained1, Retained2, Retained3)

retention12 <- c2128 %>%
  left_join(s2132) %>%
  mutate(Retained = !is.na(match)) %>%
  mutate(Retained1 = ifelse(Retained == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>%
  select(student, term, Retained1) %>%
  left_join(s2138) %>%
  mutate(Retained = !is.na(match)) %>%
  mutate(Retained2 = ifelse(Retained == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>%
  select(student, term, Retained1, Retained2)
```

The result is a data set by cohort `term`.

```
library(plyr)
retention <- rbind.fill(retention11, retention12)
  student term Retained1 Retained2 Retained3
1       A 2118         1         1         1
2       B 2118         1         1         0
3       C 2118         0         0         0
4       X 2128         1         1        NA
5       Y 2128         1         0        NA
6       Z 2128         0         0        NA
```

And so my original post wanted to figure out a way to reduce the amount of lines by using a nested loop

```
for(i in cohorts) {
         for (j in semester > cohorts) {
          assign(paste("retention",i,sep=""),
                 paste("c",i,sep="") %>% 
                   left_join(paste("s",j,sep="")) %>% 
                   mutate(Retained = !is.na(match)) %>% 
                   mutate(Retained1 = ifelse(Retained == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>% 
                   select(student, term, Retained1)
          )
         }
}
```

And this is where I remain. How might I create a loop that will reduce the amount of lines in the 3rd block of code? Hope my objective and code are much clearer this time! Thanks everyone!

Comment: I have to admit I find your question a bit confusing. Can you provide a minimal sample data of all inputs (`ugrd` and `enrollment` are missing) and the expected output for the sample data? I'm guessing there might be better ways than a nested for loop to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: @beginneR I put a few lines to describe what ugrd and enrollment are, as well as the main inputs I am using from the file. I hope that my question is a little clearer, but I will read through it again to see if it makes sense.

Comment: `paste()` returns a character vector. `dplyr` functions expect a name/symbol, so you can't just pass a character vector matching the name. Unfortunately, I don't think wrapping your character vector in `as.name()` or `as.symbol()` works either (or at least it didn't for me when I tried it a few weeks ago).

Comment: You really need to provide a reproducible example with dummy data.

Comment: @hadley I have revamped my post so that my objective and code are clearer

Comment: Why are you creating multiple data frames instead of using group by to define cohorts?